# Compiler Warning for Unnecessary Namespaces

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang

I have a lot of code that is functionally like this:

```
namespace Foo { namespace Bar { namespace Baz {

class MyType {};

Foo::Bar::Baz::MyType func(Foo::Bar::Baz::MyType const& param);

}}}
```

Since there aren't any conflicting definitions of `MyType`, this could be easily simplified like so:

```
namespace Foo { namespace Bar { namespace Baz {

class MyType {};

MyType func(MyType const& param);

}}}
```

We've saved (an embarrassing amount) of text space by beginning to delete these sorts of occurrences in our large, expansive codebase.  However, it's slow going and error-prone, since we're doing it by vgrep.

Ideally, there would be a compiler warning.  Our codebase supports three different compilers (MSVC, g++, and Clang) on three different platforms (Windows, Linux, and Mac), mostly respectively.

I couldn't find a warning to enable that would help us, and it's difficult to Google since people make the `class A { void A::method(void) {} };` error a lot (and g++ catches this, since it's not standard-compliant).  Our problem is overqualification by *namespace*, not by *type*.

So, what warning should I enable in (at least) one of the above compilers?  Are there other solutions?

Comment: Three namespaces deep isn't really all that deep, so I'm sure even PCLint is likely to complain about that one... The kinds of 'extra' warnings you can find in Visual C++ are covered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx)

Comment: Compiler warnings are generally provided because the code is a potentially causing a bug. The issue here is that there's no way that fully qualifying the name would be a problem, so it's doubtful there would be warning per-se. If it's caught by anything, it would be a style-checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wrote my own.

I made a repository on github for it, [here](https://github.com/imallett/QualityCpp). It's a refactor/generalize of some older scripts I had for similar code-quality tasks (of lesser complexity).

I originally tried basing it on [CPIP](http://cpip.sourceforge.net/), which I found to be a little buggy and much too slow.  Instead, the current version is based on a horrifically bletcherous homebrew lexer that's blazing fast (but isn't really a preprocessor).  This does lead to a number of limitations and false positives, which are documented.

However, the prototype has been *extremely* successful for us.  We were able to remove all the cruft we missed in a few hours, with false positives (due to the limitations of fake preprocessing) occurring in only 4 files (out of 829).

I hope this helps someone of the future!  Check it out!